# Renaming Columns from pivot_table

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I run a `pivot_table` on a dataframe and the resulting column names are:

```
('firstvar', 8001)    ('firstvar', 8002)    ('secondvar', 8001)    ('secondvar', 8002)
```

But before I can use the data I need to rename the columns to something along these lines:

```
firstvar_8001    firstvar_8002    secondvar_8001    secondvar_8002
```

I tried to see if this could be done when doing the pivot table but I don't think it can be.
So instead I'm looking for a solution to renaming the columns in the dataframe before I save it as a csv

I need to run this on multiple files where the 8000 codes might change so I was thinking of using `regex` but I can't find any support for renaming columns in a dataframe using `regex`.

Edit: So I realize now that the names are actually python `tuples` and I'm working on converting them to strings and joining them now.

Edit: So I found a clumsy solution. My issue was that it wouldn't allow me to rename the tuples so I ended up just exporting and re-import to flatten the levels and then renaming them in that fashion. I really don't like the solution though so if anyone has a suggestion for a better way to do it; I would really appreciate it!

Comment: if you provide the code you're using, and an example of the data frame you're working on, we can see if there's a more elegant solution

Comment: Something like this: `df.columns = ['_'.join(a,b) for a, b in df.columns]`

Comment: This worked for me. I didn't have multilevel columns, but they were a tuple because of a resampling I did. I only used regular + instead of join. Thanks man.

Answer (score 3):

Late answer but can be helpful for others...

```
my_colnames = []
for i, a in enumerate(my_pivoted_table.columns.get_level_values(1)):
    my_colnames.append(str(a) + '_' + str(my_pivoted_table.columns.get_level_values(0)[i]))
my_pivoted_table.columns = my_colnames
```