# A better way to exclude row values when doing a pandas' pivot_table?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I want to create a pivot table from a dataframe, but exclude rows which equal a certain value (in this case, in the column that I'm aggfunc-ing on, but I'd like to have a more general answer).

I managed to do this in two ways:

1) just create a copy of the original df w/o those values, and pivot on that.

2) do that into the pivot table directly, like so:

```
my_pivot = pd.pivot_table(
               source_df[source_df['some_column'] != 'row value_to_exclude'],
               index = ['some id for example'], 
               values = ['some_column'], 
               aggfunc=lambda x: len(x.unique()),
               margins=False)
```

I'm wondering if there's a cleaner, more pythonic way to do that.

Also, while we're here, can I pass to pivot_table how I want my aggregated column to be named?
[EDIT] To clarify, I meant how to set the name of the column where the aggregated values will be in the pivot table, during creation of the pivot, not afterwards, as you would regularly rename columns in any df.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your first part looks OK to me, FWIW. As for the second part, just stick the pivoted table into some variable, say `pivoted`, and then use `pivoted.columns = some_list_of_column_names`.

Comment: Not sure I follow you Ami. Toda.

Comment: see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22537079/renaming-columns-from-pivot-table). Hope it helps. If not, I suggest you edit this question to indicate more precisely what you want.

Comment: Ah, I understand where my confusion comes from. You OKed the way I removed rows from the df I pivoted on. Your answer was on renaming. Edited. Tnx.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you want to do it within the pivot_table statement rather than after?  I doesn't look like there is, although if you want to do it all on one line, you could tack on a `.rename(columns={})` at the end.  That's the other standard way to rename columns.

Comment: @JohnE thank John. Just thought there might be a neater way. Anyway, that's just a side note for my question. The real question is how to pivot only rows that have (or don't have) certain values.

Comment: Well, the way you did it seems fine.  You avoid creating a permanent copy of the dataframe, which is good if you have any memory constraints.  FWIW, I would do it as a method rather than function  -- `df[mask].pivot_table()` instead of `pd.pivot_table(df[mask])` -- but I don't think that matters in any real way.  Newer alternate ways of doing something like this might be with `pipe()` or `assign()` but again I don't know if there's any real advantage to those here.

Comment: @JohnE Thanks John. Not enough karma to upvote your comment I'm afraid.